# Modifying nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

How to handle nested lists in Python? I am having problem figuring out the syntax. Like example:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
```

I want to square all the elements in this list. I tried:

```
[m*m for m in l]
```

But that doesn't work and throws up:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by
>   non-int of type 'list'

because of the nested lists I guess?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
>>> [[e*e for e in m] for m in l]
     |-nested list-|
    |----   complete list    ---|
[[1, 4, 9], [25, 36, 49]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes one gets lucky.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought it would be so easy.

Comment: I know this is [SOTBO](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SOTBO) for some of you, but your result won't get stored unless you assign it, as in 
`l = [[e*e for e in m] for m in l]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] != [1,2,3,4,5,6]    

[map(lambda x: x *x,sl) for sl in l]    #List comprhension
```

Comment: I usely avoid lambda wherever I can! But +1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted the answer to look like this:

```
[[1, 4, 9], [25, 36, 49]]
```

You could do something like this:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]

for x in range(len(l)):
    for y in range(len(l[x])):
        l[x][y] = l[x][y] * l[x][y]

print l
```

Obviously, the list comprehension answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recursive function, something like this:

```
def square(el):
    if type(el) == list:
        return [square(x) for x in el]
    else:
        return el**2;
```

I'd rather not get into the correctness of `type(el) == list` here, but you get the gist.

Of course, this is also doable with a list-comprehension, as many people have pointer out, *provided that* the structure is always the same. This recursive function can handle any level of recursion, and lists containing both lists and numbers.

Comment: Recursion is invaluable for trees of varying depth, but propably not needed here.